# Android-Studio upgraded from 0.1.9 to 0.2.0 causing gradle build errors now

Tags: gradle, android-studio

My current project had been building with Gradle just fine, since
I created it (about a month ago), after acquiring Android-Studio.
[I installed some earlier updates to Android-Studio, and had no
problems with those.]

But, today, after I upgraded Android-Studio's newest update to a
"July 11th" build, going from version 0.1.9 to 0.2.0, my
project started complaining that Gradle now needs to be at
minimum of 0.5.0. (My project was asking for Gradle 0.4, and this
new Studio upgrade flagged my Gradle build and stated it would
NOW need this new higher minimum of Gradle.

So, what I'm unclear about:  I've been assuming Gradle is PART of
(bundled with) Android Studio.

Do I now need to get a newer Gradle, as a separate product/update?

I'm confused!!!

EDIT: (This is happening under Windows-7).

Answer (score 85):

### Solution for me without reinstalling or creating a new project:

**Step 1:** Change line in `build.gradle` from:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.4'
}
```

to

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
}
```

Note: for newer versions of gradle you may need to change it to `0.6.+` instead.

**Step 2:** In the `<YourProject>.iml` file, delete the entire`<component name="FacetManager">[...]</component>` tag.

**Step 3** *(Maybe not necessary)*: In the Android SDK manager, install (if not already installed) `Android Support Repository` under Extras.

---

Info found [here](http://tools.android.com/knownissues)

Comment: Only needed step 1 now (version 0.2.9)

Comment: In Android Studio 0.2.11 (a) there was no `dependencies...` block in `build.gradle`, (b) My project's .iml file had no FacetManager component, and (c) I already have Android Support Repository installed...at a loss

Comment: Only needed step 1 and a change to gradle-wrapper.properties (changed to 1.9) when updating to 0.4.2.

Comment: Still didn't get it running with the steps u offered with error: _Error:Could not find any version that matches de.richsource.gradle.plugins:gwt-gradle-plugin:0.5+.
Required by:
    :Android:unspecified_  Running Andriod Studio(Beta) 0.8.2.   How do i install new versions of Gradle?

Comment: I wonder why every one is calling it gradle, isnt it the ANDROID PLUGING FOR GRADLE, not the gradle itself ... pls correct me if I  m wrong. How do I knwo which version of gradle or android gradle plugin to use with which version of android studio ?  Thnx

Comment: Step 1 doesn't work if you do not have the .jar and .pom files of the version you are upgrading to.

Comment: Can anyone actually explain the *why* of these steps?

Answer (score 3):

Basically if you follow the issues in [this link](http://tools.android.com/knownissues) for 0.2 you'll likely get yourself fixed, I had the same problems with 0.2

Answer (score 2):

Gradle should be updated already, you just need to let your previous projects know gradle has been updated.

[Source](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html#Troubleshooting)

Edit your build.gradle file to show this:

```
dependencies {
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
}
```

This should only be required for projects created with the previous version of Android Studio. New projects you create will have that by default.

Comment: Yes, that was my understanding, too. However, when I do that, I now get errors during the attempt to build.

Comment: Specifically:Gradle: 
FAILURE: Could not determine which tasks to execute.

* What went wrong:
Task 'assemble' not found in root project 'Slims_SchedProject'.

* Try:
Run gradle tasks to get a list of available tasks.

Comment: And even worse, when I try to create a new project, I now get:Failed to import Gradle project: Could not fetch model of type 'IdeaProject' using Gradle distribution

Comment: Did you uninstall your previous Android Studio? On the troubleshooting steps its stated that installing over previous version could cause a few problema

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I finally resolved this, by completely de-installing Android-Studio,
and then installing the latest (0.2.0) from scratch.

EDIT: I also had to use the Android SDK-Manager, and install the component
in the 'Extras' section called the Android Support Repository
(as mentioned elsewhere).

Note: This does NOT fix my old existing project...that one still will not
build, as indicated above.

But, it DOES solve the issue of now being able to at least create NEW
projects going forward, that build ok using 'Gradle'. (So, basically,
I re-created my proj from scratch under a new name, and copied all
my code and project xml-files, etc, from the old project, into the
newly-created one.)

[As an aside: I've got an idea, Google! Why don't you refer to versions
of Android-Studio using numbers like 0.1.9 and 0.2.0, but then when users
click on 'About' menu item, or search elsewhere for what version they
are running, you could baffle them with crap like 'the July 11th build'
or aka, some build number with 6 or 8 digits of numbering, and make
them wonder what version they actually have!  That will keep the
developers guessing...really will sort the wheat from the chaff, etc.]

For example, I originally installed a kit named:
android-studio-bundle-130.687321-windows.exe

Today, I got the "0.2.0" kit???, and it has a name like:
android-studio-bundle-130.737825-windows.exe

Yep, this version #ing system is about as clear as mud.
Why bother with the illusion of version#s, when you don't use them!!!???

Answer (score 1):

if you get this error

```
Gradle: 
FAILURE: Could not determine which tasks to execute.
* What went wrong:
Task 'assemble' not found in root project 'MyProject'.
* Try:
Run gradle tasks to get a list of available tasks.
```

You need to edit your Projects .iml file. not the one under src. the one that is like               myappProject.iml' delete the whole component name = facetmanager

```
<module external.system.id="GRADLE" type="JAVA_MODULE" version="4">
<component name="FacetManager">
...remove this element and everything inside such as <facet> elements...
</component>
<component name="NewModuleRootManager" inherit-compiler-output="true">
...keep this part...
</component
```

Answer (score 1):

now you can use the last 1.0.0-rc1
this way :

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0-rc1'
```

This needs Gradle 2.0 if you don't have it Android Studio will ask you to download it

Answer (score 1):

For people who have this problem today(to example to switch from 2.8.0 to 2.10.0), move to file gradle-wrapper.properties and set distributionUrl with the value you need.
`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip`

I changed 2.8.0 to 2.10.0 and dont forget to Sync after