# Android studio is not running my project

Tags: android, android-studio

**Event log:**

> Gradle build finished with 1 error(s)

**Gradle console:**

> :app:dexDebug The system cannot find the path specified.
>
> FAILED
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
>
>   > com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
>   >     C:\Users\xxxxxxxxx\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\21.1.1\dx.bat
>   >     --dex --no-optimize --output C:\Users\xxxxxxxxx\AndroidStudioProjects\Studioone\app\build\intermediates\dex\debug
>   >     --input-list=C:\Users\pabhuvignesh.k\AndroidStudioProjects\Studioone\app\build\intermediates\tmp\dex\debug\inputList.txt
>   >     Error Code:   1 Output:   The system cannot find the path specified.
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>
> BUILD FAILED

**Stacktrace:**

> Gradle build finished with 1 error(s)

Comment: Is this a new Android Studio project? Has it compiled before? What version? What version of Gradle are you using?

Comment: Does that path/file exist on your development machine ?

Comment: @jesses.co.tt yes this is new one and i am compiling it for fist time. and studio version is 1.0 gradle version is also 1.0. And all the path and files are exists.

Comment: Studio 1.0 Requires Gradle 2.1+ ... go to Preferences > Gradle and change your Gradle to the default wrapper

Comment: @jesses.co.tt but how to upgrade it.

Comment: Do you not get a prompt from AS ? Anyways... that should be a separate question...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17727645/how-to-update-gradle-in-android-studio

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17634708/android-studio-upgraded-from-0-1-9-to-0-2-0-causing-gradle-build-errors-now/17648742#17648742

Comment: @jesses.co.tt now my gradle got updated automatically to 2.2.1 when i did this"Gradle to the default wrapper" But still no use. same error

Comment: Ok, sorry, thats all the advice I have...

Comment: ensure your internet connection was connected during Gradle..

Comment: @Amitabha Biswas it is working

Comment: How to solved it? @PrabhuVigneshRajagopal

Comment: @Amitabha Biswas i didn't solved my primary issue...  I said internet is working...

Comment: Let's try Tools -> android -> Sync project with gradle files..

Comment: Done..  But nothing changed.. same issue retains @Amitabha Biswas