# How update plugins in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, plugins, dependencies, android-gradle-plugin

I ran my android project after almost a week and I got this message:

> Plugin is too old, please update to a more recent version, or set
>   ANDROID_DAILY_OVERRIDE environment variable to
>   "a8faa180fc282060c9b8ec88f9bdcc9072121284"

**How do I update my Plugins?** I am using android Studio 2.0. Here is my build.gradle project file

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha1'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha1 to com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha3 which is the latest version.

Comment: They're not very good with updating their website, but if you go to the source (the distribution channel) you can see all of the available releases of the plugin and when they were published: https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.android.tools.build.gradle/

Comment: I have changed my build:gradle to 2.0.0-alpha3 but it is still giving the same error.

Comment: @user3082254 - Rebuild project

Answer (score 5):

Open your IDE. Open a project. Then look for the following:

If you are using Windows you go to `Help` -> `Check for updates`

If you are using Mac, you go to `Android Studio` (next to the Mac symbol, in the top left) -> `Check for updates`

Alternatively when you launch your SDK Manger, it automatically searches for updates to your plugins. Navigate to SDK Tools.

Answer (score 3):

**UDPATE (may-2016)**

update to lastest

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
  }
```

You can specify the Gradle version in either the **File > Project Structure > Project menu in Android Studio**, or **by editing the Gradle distribution reference in the gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties file**

```
distributionUrl = https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip
```

check [gradle revisions](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html#revisions)

> ```
> The Android Gradle Plugin and Gradle
>  Android Gradle Plugin    Requires Gradle
>  1.0.0 - 1.1.3     2.2.1 - 2.3
>  1.2.0 - 1.3.1     2.2.1 - 2.9
>  1.5.0     2.2.1+
>  2.*   2.10+
> ```

check [answer for update gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17634708/android-studio-upgraded-from-0-1-9-to-0-2-0-causing-gradle-build-errors-now/17648742#17648742)

Answer (score 2):

Change the line

`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha1'`

to a latest version like

`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha3`
(latest version at the moment of answering)